# How can I incorporate pressure point attacks?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

I am wondering if there are any classes, alternatives, or anything else than roleplay to incorporate pressure point techniques in D&D 3.5.
The monk's stunning fist (or the feat) could be roleplayed that way, but after that feats like Freezing the lifeblood, while can be an answer to my question, have ridiculous (in my opinion) prerequisites.

Are there any other options to represent pressure point techniques?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd address you to the wide array of feats for which Improved Unarmed Strike is a prerequisite in Pathfinder (search for "Improved Unarmed Strike" in [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/feat-tree)<sup>D20PFSRD</sup>).

Many of them may be seamlessly converted to D&D3.5 and easily re-skinned in order to meet your campaign's flavor.

Answer (score 3):

**Pressure Point Strike**
In the column Class Acts: Monk entitled "Pressure Point Attacks" (*Dragon* #336 103) is the the general feat Pressure Point Strike. Its prerequisites include Dexterity 13, Wisdom 13, Base Attack Bonus +8, Knowledge (arcana) 5 ranks, the feats Improved Unarmed Strike (*PH* 96-7) and Stunning Fist (*PH* 101), and--most egregiously--*ki* strike (magic). This last limits the feat to those who are willing to go at least 4 levels into monk.

The feat itself is... interesting, giving the monk the option of spending 1-5 stunning fist attempts to assist allies by removing conditions (e.g. fatigued, paralysis, stunned, sickened--not dazed, though) or to inconvenience foes by giving them conditions other than stunned (e.g. blind, deaf, paralyzed) or by otherwise reducing their combat effectiveness (e.g. lowering a creature's spell resistance, preventing a creature from casting spells and using spell-like abilities for 1d4 rounds).

All hindrances the feat bestows on the monk's foes are resisted by Fortitude saving throws--most monsters' *best* saving throw--so while it *pretends* to improve the monk's offensive versatility, it doesn't really.

The ability to spend 5 stunning fist attempts to generate an effect like the spell *greater dispel magic* [abjur] (*PH* 223)--even if only by touching and ally and even then only *versus* a single spell or spell-like ability--is probably why the feat has the Base Attack Bonus +8 prerequisite. There must be *some* niche application of being able to generate an effect like the spell *greater dispel magic* as an extraordinary ability.

A generous DM could give this feat to monks for free at level 11 (when they could normally meet the feat's printed prerequisites), level 4 (when they could meet the feat's printed prerequisites except for Base Attack Bonus), or even level 1 (just 'cause) and not risk unbalancing the campaign.

Answer (score 2):

Generally when my players want to do pressure point attacks I treat them as called shots.  One thing to keep in mind is that pressure point attacks are generally there to cause pain and therefore distract the opponent, so if it's successful I will make the victim make a Body/Fortitude/Stamina check, and if it fails, apply a rule like distracted, or dazed, or blind, etc.  to fit the attack.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go monk for that personally, not exclusively. The many rogue feats in Complete Scoundrel (I think they call them ambush feats) look promising. Something I like in particular, you may be able to use or twist some of the mechanics from *Pathfinder*'s [Butcher prestige class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/3rd-party-prestige-classes/4-winds-fantasy-gaming/butcher).

Basically, you look at others' discernable anatomy as pieces of meat and are more efficient in your handling of weapons regarding them. But again, roguey in nature. I'd say this is about as close as I've been able to project a character, I was once going to play a dwarf dual-wielding fighter rogue with it. It looks fun to say the least.

> Dazing Slice (Ex)
>
> A butcher knows everything about the way a body works, including where the nerves are. Beginning at 7th level, whenever a butcher successfully severs a limb, his target is dazed for 1 round (Will save DC 10 + ½ butcher’s class level + butcher’s Int modifier to resist).
>
> Stunning Sever (Ex)
>
> The nerve damage a butcher causes freezes his target in place. Beginning at 10th level, whenever a butcher successfully severs a limb, his target is stunned for 1 round.